# SimpleSchema custom validation message not showing

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I am trying to implement a custom validation function which can return either `true` (if the field is valid) or some custom error message. Here's my current attempt:

```
global.Messages = Models.Messages = new Mongo.Collection 'messages'

MessagesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    label: "Message",
    max: 200,
    custom: ->
      if @obj.content.includes("a")
        true
      else
        "not contain a"
}, {tracker: Tracker})

Messages.attachSchema MessagesSchema
```

This is a contrived example but still, it's not working. The conditional in the `custom` function is run, and when `true` gets returned then the record does save. However, if `"not contain a"` gets returned, it *does not* become the validation message displayed on the client. It just says `content is invalid`, and I'm not sure how to customize this message. Here's the template code:

```
  {{#autoForm collection="Messages" id="insertMessageForm" type="insert"}}
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Add message</legend>
      {{> afFieldInput type='text' name='content'}}
      {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='content'}}
      <span class="help-block">{{afFieldMessage name='content'}}</span>
      {{/if}}
    </fieldset>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Insert</button>
  {{/autoForm}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems with my original code.

First of all, I didn't specify how I was requiring `SimpleSchema` but it should be done this way; this uses the new `node-simpl-schema` package which is what `meteor-simple-schema` migrated to:

```
SimpleSchema = require('simpl-schema').default
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);
```

Validation messages are mapped to keys:

```
SimpleSchema.setDefaultMessages
  messages:
    en: 
      "notA": "doesnt contain a"
```

The `messages` and `en` hashes are necessary for it to be the correct structure.

**important point**: the return value of `custom` is *not* the message that gets displayed on the client. It is a *key*, pointing to the entry in the default messages object.

For example:

```
custom: ->
  if @obj.content.includes("a")
    true
  else
    "notA"
```

This will end up showing the message `"doesnt contain a"`